# How can i preview Alphacam Drawing files?

Tags: c#, preview

I am trying to preview Alphacam files (.ard) using C#. In the explorer windows preview pane i can preview this files.

I tried to use this [way](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/183) to preview but in regedit  there is no subkey named shellex that contains a subkey named {8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}.[ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-a-preview-handler)

I do not know how explorer previews without this subkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but I did not use the thumbnail way.

First, I created a tempdrawing, and then I saved that tempdrawing as a preview.

```
AcamRouter1 = new AlphaCAMRouter.App();
AlphaCAMRouter.Drawing Ciz = AcamRouter1.CreateTempDrawing();
Ciz.InsertDrawing(label24.Text,0,0,0);
string strFileName = AcamRouter1.LicomdirPath + "\\PreviewNoBorder.png";
Ciz.SavePreviewImageEx(strFileName, AcamPreviewImageType.acamImagePNG, 700, 500, AcamView.acamViewXY, false, 10,false);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(strFileName)));
```